# Mocking a method within the context of another class

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I have two classes Parameter and ParameterList. The ParameterList class is an ArrayList made up of Parameters. There is a method getParameterByKey that finds the parameter in the list by key value. I don't want to mock Parameter.getValueString() since I want the value to be different depending on the key and that would require mocks for each key/value. Any input is appreciated.

I want to say go get the key "A431" and return "BOSTON" (etc) but I am getting  "java.lang.NullPointerException".

```
    when(mockedParmList.getParameterByKey("A431").getValueString()).thenReturn("BOSTON");
    when(mockedParmList.getParameterByKey("A432").getValueString()).thenReturn("NYC")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to mock the call to mockedParmList.getParameterByKey(). Otherwise, it's returning null, and then you're calling getValueString() on it, which gets you to the NPE.

```
when(mockedParmList.getParameterByKey("A431")).thenReturn(new Parameter(...))
```

Either you can use an actual Parameter value (probably), or you can mock the Parameter that you're going to return.

Comment: I was hoping to get around having to mock the return for each value that I want but that does solve the null issue